# Roll a dice function using a timer that animate's a picturebox and returns a random value

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, wait

I'm trying to build a display for a die roll. What I want to do is flicker images of random faces on the die, then end with the face that shows the number rolled. *After* this happens, I want the function to continue and return the number of the die roll. Here's what I have

```
public int RollDie()
{
    RollNum = dieRoll.Next(1, 7);
    DispCount = 0;
    Timer Time = new Timer();
    Time.Interval = TimerInterval;
    Time.Tick += DisplayRollHandler;
    Time.Start();
    System.Threading.Thread DispThread = new System.Threading.Thread(Time.Start);
    DispThread.Start();
    DispThread.Join();
    return RollNum;
}
private void DisplayRollHandler(object sender, EventArgs evt)
{
    if (DispCount < TargetDispCount)
    {
        Random Nums = new Random();
        Display.BackgroundImage = Faces[Nums.Next(0, 6)];
        DispCount++;
    }
    else
    {
        ((Timer)sender).Stop();
        Display.BackgroundImage = Faces[RollNum - 1];
    }
}
```

where `dieRoll` is a random object and `Display` is a Panel. The image flicker works, and it does return the number of the roll consistently. Unfortunately, it doesn't wait for the display flicker to finish before continuing, which is a problem when I have automatic messages that pop up after the die is rolled.

I'm a fairly inexperienced programmer, so I'm probably missing a really basic concept. I know that if I could abstract this into a method call, I can wait for a method call to finish, but I can't figure out how to do that without using a `Thread.Sleep` call and freezing the program.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any reason your using a Timer and not a Background worker? Just tap into the `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` method to do the roll, then once its finished tap into the `backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted` method to know when the roll dice operation has completed.

Comment: I am not a C# programmer but the function you are starting the thread with is non-blocking. It just processes the Start function and finishes, this is why you can join instantly.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I'm unfamiliar with Background worker. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: @EralpB I figured something along those lines was happening, but I don't know any ways that work, either. Thanks for confirming, though.

Comment: I'll try and get back to you tomor with a working solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrote a little `Dice` class which will provide the desired values to you:

```
public class Dice
{
    private Random _Random;
    private BackgroundWorker _Worker;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Dice"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public Dice()
    {
        _Random = new Random();

        InitializeDefaultValues();
        InitializeBackgroundWorker();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the dice finished rolling.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler Rolled;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs while the dice is rolling and the value has changed.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler RollingChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the including maximum value that the dice can return.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The maximum value.
    /// </value>
    [DefaultValue(6)]
    public int Maximum { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the including minimum value that the dice can return.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The minimum.
    /// </value>
    [DefaultValue(1)]
    public int Minimum { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the result that this dice currently has.
    /// </summary>
    public int Result { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the duration of the rolling.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The duration of the rolling.
    /// </value>
    [DefaultValue(typeof(TimeSpan), "00:00:03")]
    public TimeSpan RollingDuration { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts rolling the dice.
    /// </summary>
    public void Roll()
    {
        if (!_Worker.IsBusy)
        {
            CheckParameters();
            _Worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void CheckParameters()
    {
        if (Minimum >= Maximum)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Minimum value must be less than the Maximum value.");
        }

        if (RollingDuration <= TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The RollingDuration must be greater zero.");
        }
    }

    private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
    {
        _Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _Worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        _Worker.DoWork += OnWorkerDoWork;
        _Worker.ProgressChanged += OnWorkerProgressChanged;
        _Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += OnWorkerRunWorkerCompleted;
    }

    private void InitializeDefaultValues()
    {
        Minimum = 1;
        Maximum = 6;
        Result = Minimum;
        RollingDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    }

    private void OnWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var finishTime = DateTime.UtcNow + RollingDuration;

        while (finishTime > DateTime.UtcNow)
        {
            Result = _Random.Next(Minimum, Maximum + 1);
            _Worker.ReportProgress(0);
            // ToDo: Improve sleep times for more realistic rolling.
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }

    private void OnWorkerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseEvent(RollingChanged);
    }

    private void OnWorkerRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseEvent(Rolled);
    }

    private void RaiseEvent(EventHandler handler)
    {
        var temp = handler;

        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

In a first and simple example i simply added a button to a form (`buttonRoll`) and a label (`labelDiceResult`) and added the follwing code (don't forget to add the initialize method into the form constructor):

```
private void InitializeDice()
{
    _Dice = new Dice();
    _Dice.RollingChanged += OnDiceRollingChanged;
    _Dice.Rolled += OnDiceRolled;
}

void OnDiceRolled(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonRoll.Enabled = true;
}

void OnDiceRollingChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ToDo: Select desired picture from image list depending on _Dice.Result
    labelDiceResult.Text = _Dice.Result.ToString();
}

private void OnButtonRollClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonRoll.Enabled = false;
    _Dice.Roll();
}
```

As a last step i would maybe tweak the `Thread.Sleep(50)` call to use different values over time by using a calculated list depending on the rising part of a sinus and the desired duration to let the dice slow down over time. But i let this part open for the reader (or a next question).

Comment: Let me make sure I understand what you've done here:
Basically, you wrote a background worker that sleeps a time (50 milliseconds, though you suggest making that vary, which I like). Each time that elapses, it raises an event to change the die face if it's not done, or raise an event to finish the roll off if it is done. Is that correct?
So how do I stall the thread that called the die roll, so that it doesn't get the value until the die display stops?

Comment: @DavidLegg: There are two events: `RollingChanged` while the dice will support you with several valid intermediate results. When the rolling is finished it raises the `Rolled` event. So simply ignore the changed event and only listen to the finish event and get the final value only at this point in time.

Comment: Okay, I think that should work well. I'll let you know if it works as soon as I get a chance to implement it.

Comment: Just implemented your solution. Works like a charm. Just had to break up the roll into a call to start and an event listener for when it finished. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

There is a fundamental error with this solution in that the randomizer should never be instantiated within the dice object itself.  A simple test will show why.  Simply add another dice object to the form and roll both at the same time.  Notice something funny?  They are always the same!

This is because, as a default, the randomizer used the current time to seed the generator.  Creating two (or more) objects in the same part of code will result in all of the dice objects having the same seed, and thus the same result when rolled every time.

A better solution would involve creating a static singleton class that would handle all the rolling (randomizing) all the dice for you.

Here is a quick example (using a Dice class that is a bit more generic):

```
public static class DiceRoller
{
    private static Random _roller;

    public static void RollDice(Dice dice)
    {
        if (dice.Faces.Count < 1)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("A dice must contain at least 1 side to be rolled.");

        if (_roller == null)
            _roller = new Random();

        int index = _roller.Next(dice.Faces.Count);
        dice.SetFacingIndex(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is true, but not really a concern for my code. Only one dice is in use at one time, and another cannot be created at the same instant. You're correct that if this were possible, it would be an issue. That being said, I see you have the class and the random object as `static`. What would happen if the class weren't `static`, but the `Random` object was?